'numpy.ndarray' a problem in flask inserting in Ai model
I want to insert the string into the machine learning model, but it keeps saying this:
    prediction = model.predict(email_features_array)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'predict'

I don't know what the problem is, I changed the decoding method several times.
This is the function I'm using after I do vectorzation:
def predict():
    email_text ="hello world"
    cv = CountVectorizer()
    email_features_array = cv.fit_transform([email_text])
    # email_features_array = fit_count_vectorizer(email_text)
    print(email_features_array)
    # Assume `model` is already defined and trained
    prediction = model.predict(email_features_array)

    # Apply the pre-trained model to predict the probability of the email being phishing
    probability = model.predict_proba(email_features_array)
    if prediction[0] == 1:
        result = 'Phishing'
        probability_score = probability[0][1] * 100
        print(result, probability_score)
    else:
        result = 'Legitimate'
        probability_score = probability[0][0] * 100
        print(result, probability_score)

I expect that there is a problem with how I decode it but not sure.

The problem is model is a numpy.ndarray object which has no attribute predict, so model.predict cannot work. Given all we know is you "Assume model is already defined and trained" it's hard to say more.
